# Can't get user name and email in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

When I Sign in with Firebase after writing Name, last name and take profile picture, I press "Finish Registration" and starts activity of user account and the name of user and profile picture not showing besides user email address. But when I restart my application user name and profile picture is showing. I want to show name and profile picture after registering user data(name, last name, profile picture). How can I solve it ?

*Registering User Data Activity code*

```
 finishRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ProgressDialog loadData = ProgressDialog.show(RegisterUserInformation.this,"Sending data to Server", "Please wait", true,false);

            UserProfileChangeRequest request = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                        .setDisplayName("" + name.getText().toString() + " " + lastname.getText().toString()).build();


            mUser.updateProfile(request);

            mStorageReference.child("Online Scheduler").child("Users").child("" + mUser.getUid()).child("Profile Picture").putFile(selectedImage)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                               loadData.dismiss();
                            }
                        });




            HashMap<String, Object> userData = new HashMap<>();
            userData.put("Name", name.getText().toString());
            userData.put("Last name", lastname.getText().toString());
            userData.put("Email", mUser.getEmail());
            userData.put("UId", mUser.getUid());

            myRef.child("Online Scheduler").child("Users").child("" + mUser.getUid()).child("User Information").setValue(userData).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                       loadData.dismiss();


                    Intent goToUserAccount = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Account.class);
                       startActivity(goToUserAccount);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

*User Account Activity code*

```
 if(mUser != null)
           {
               name.setText(mUser.getDisplayName());
               email.setText(mUser.getEmail());

               Log.d(logTag,"" + mUser.getDisplayName());
               Log.d(logTag, "" + mUser.getEmail());

               //Get profile picture for facebook authentication user.
               Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mUser.getPhotoUrl()).listener(new RequestListener<Uri, GlideDrawable>() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean onException(Exception e, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                       progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                       return false;
                   }

                   @Override
                   public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                       progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                       return false;
                   }
               }).into(avatar); // Get profile picture for facebook authentication user.

               //Get profile picture for email authentication user.
               sRef.child("Online Scheduler").child("Users").child("" + mUser.getUid()).child("Profile Picture")
                       .getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(final Uri uri) {
                     Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(uri).listener(new RequestListener<Uri, GlideDrawable>() {
                         @Override
                         public boolean onException(Exception e, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

                             Log.d(logTag,"" + uri.toString());

                             progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                             return false;
                         }

                         @Override
                         public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

                             Log.d(logTag,"" + uri.toString());
                             progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                             return false;
                         }
                     }).into(avatar);
                   }
               }); //Get profile picture for email authentication user.
           }
```

Comment: Can you post your code where you are having issues?

Comment: I have already posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some EventListener to the firesdatabase so that you will listen to the changes; The onDataChange callback method will be called whenever you change firebasedatabase. 
Example; EventListener, ChildEventListener, ValueEventListener

```
mStorageReference.child("Online 
Scheduler").child("Users").child("Uid")
.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) 
    }
 });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events